# svn diff: does not support mixed target types

Tags: svn, diff

I was trying to create diff between 2 svn branches, so I've tried the command:

```
svn diff https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch1url https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch2url
```

There I've got the error message:

```
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help diff' for more information
svn: E205000: 'svn diff [-r N[:M]] [TARGET[@REV]...]' does not support mixed target types. Try using the --old and --new options or one of the shorthand invocations listed in 'svn help diff'.
svn: E205000: Error parsing arguments
svn: E200009: Cannot mix repository and working copy targets
```

After checking help, I've dared another try:

```
svn diff --old=https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch1url
 --new=https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch2url
```

and got another error message:

```
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help diff' for more information
svn: E205000: Path 'https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch2url' not relative to base URLs
```

I'm quite confused what to do now. Coming from git, it's quite frustrating not being able to do the simplest task... 
I can always import the project to git repository, but it would be quite an overkill...

How to create diff between 2 branches in SVN for my case?

Comment: It should work. Can you checkout `https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch1url`? `svn checkout https://mysvn/myrepo/branches/branch1url /temporary/directory`

Comment: @uzsolt yes, actually both branches are checkouted.

Comment: Hm. And what says the `svn  info --show-item url /checkout/directory`?

Answer (score 1):

I received your first error message when there was a space in my branch's URL.  Enclosing the URL in quotation marks resolved the issue.